# Can't access an external variable from another file using exec (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, exec

I have two files, in the first one where functions are defined named 'functions.py' and the second one where I can call those functions named 'test.py' and I am executing some code with exec from 'test.py' and asking it's asking for the variable initialized in 'for' loop while being 'for' loop through exec but I am getting error

> NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Details:

In 'functions.py' I describe a function named 'forloop' like this:

```
def forloop(current, maximum, increment, code):
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    for x in range(current, maximum, increment):
        exec(str(code), frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals)
```

And in 'test.py' I am calling this function

```
from functions import *

forloop(1,5,1,"""
echo(x)
""")
```

Now I am executing it with another exec in another file but, I am pretty sure that problem lies in here.

I think I should be able to access 'x' from this exec but, I can't, it gives me an error saying

> NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Please tell me why 'x' isn't defined and how can I get 'x' from that file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try importing the forloop method from your functions.py file into your test.py file?

Your test.py file should look something like this:

```
from functions import forloop

forloop(1,5,1,"""
echo(x)
""")
```

Comment: I have actually imported it like this 'from functions import *' but I thought it was obvious but, it wasn't so, I will edit my question, sorry and please do you know what else can be causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

first on test.py you must:

```
import functions
```

...then you can call it as

```
functions.forloop
```

cheers!

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering but, I have 'from functions import *' done this in my test.py but, it still gives the same error and I have edited my question and have added that code in question for no further confusion and please if you can help me, edit your answer.

Comment: when you use import, you import variales and functions...  but not the x of a for loop.
you can't use X because it is only in the for loop of forloop, if you want some output declare it in the return of your function forloop.
cheers again!